# Windows installer removing generated log files

Tags: windows-installer

Hi I have windows installer that install my program and uninstall it.
everything with installation goes fine but for uninstall part.
My program is generating Log files in "program location\Log\" directory.
I would like to add custom command to clear this folder before or after uninstallation so the uninstall process will completly remove the directory and does not leave mess in program files system.

Any idea how to do this.
Also i do not want to add additional file for this, if it is possible.

thank you for your suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to add bat file that is executed when uninstall happens and this will clear up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a RemoveFile operation to delete the log files.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371201(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Where can i find the action in installer pls?